# How to remove vertical image gaps in android

Tags: android

I kept my image size as 320*480 but it shows blank space in vertical sides,Please give some advice.Here is my xml code please suggest me..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `imageview`